# Why was Shechem designated as a city of refuge?

Tags: vayechi, joshua--book-of, city-of-refuge

The city of Shechem was given to Yosef by Yaakov ([Bereshis 48:22](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.48.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) yet when the Jewish people entered Israel Yehoshua designated the city as a city of refuge [(Yehoshua 20:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Joshua.20.7?lang=bi)). Why was this done? Doesn't this designation negate Yaakov's earlier gift?

---

Note: I realize some commentaries read 48:22 as not referring to the city itself, I am only asking according to the other commentaries who do

Answer (score 3):

Schechem was chosen likely because it was a large city in the left middle third of Eretz Yisrael. Look up a map of the 6 cities. They are spaced out. Just because is was a city of refuge doesn't make it not a city of Efraim, just as Hebron being a one doesn't make it not a city of Judah.

Comment: And note that Hebron was explicitly given to Caleb. (IIRC.)